# Can I move the opening of my screen door from the middle to the left?

Tags: doors

Hi We have a 12 ft sliding glass door off of our living room to our patio. It opens in the center third. Is there any way that the opening can be shifted to the left side and have the two fixed sections to the right? I would replace the whole thing but it would be very expensive to get the same quality as we have, which the past owners had installed. And honestly cannot afford it. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Pictures would help.

Answer (score 1):

Your post says "screen door" but it sounds like you want to change the sliding glass door and the screen along with it. Most glass door units are modular, the glass sections (stationary and sliding) are separate pieces and the track runs the whole width of the unit. If this is the case it may be possible to switch things around.

Take a good look at the unit, the sliding door should lift up and inwards for removal. Once removed you may be able to see whether or not the stationary units can be removed. Look for screws on the inside and outside that are holding the units in place. The stationary units can usually be lifted up and removed as well. If we represent the original arrangement as A-B-C (with "B" being the sliding door) you might be able to replace them in this configuration:
 B-C-A.

The panels are heavy, don't try it alone. Prepare a flat area to lay down the sliding door so you can refurbish/lubricate the wheels while you have it off (I use sawhorses). Some old glass units are NOT tempered safety glass and could hurt you terribly if broken, be careful. The weatherstripping scheme, as well as the latch, may require some ingenuity as the setup will not be the same.

Not all glass door assemblies are made to take apart like described, especially custom stuff.

Comment: To remove the sliding section you have to raise the wheels (lower the door) to provide some play so you can lift it over/off the track. There are usually adjustment screws accessed through holes at the bottom corners.